# How to execute a command in command prompt on different server using C#

Tags: c#, cmd

Currently, I have a script(run on command prompt) which I run on the different different server to generate a new user on window. I am passing username, startdate and enddate. So, once enddate is over, user credentials will expire.

Now, I would like to make a application which run  automatically or on some event. I will just pass - Server IP (where I want to run this script), username , startdate and enddate.

I am not getting how to do it. I found some link which helps me to execute command on the same server but not on different server. I need your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sort of event? Just listen to it and trigger a call to your script.

Comment: Events means - I have a .NET application. I want to execute it from this .NET application. That I will mange once I got the execution code.

Comment: So what is the trouble to listen to the event? Or what is the trouble to run the script? Share your code please.

Comment: Hi..There is no trouble to listen to the event but trouble in run the script. I have idea how to do it so I don't have code. I need code that is why I am here.